# Selenium Grid 2 from mac hub to windows node

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-grid, geb, selenium-grid2

I am setting up selenium grid to be able to test IE in a Virtual Machine.  I am running into:

> geb.driver.DriverCreationException: failed to create driver from callback

which generally means the driver is not being found.  I'm pointing it to the correct location, however something isn't working.  FYI  refers to my hub machine's intranet IP address.

Here are my files/commands:

From Mac hub terminal:

> java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar -role hub

From Windows node terminal:

> C:\selenium-server>java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar -role node -hub http://:4444/grid/register -browser browserName="internet explorer",version=10.0,platform=WINDOWS -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:\IEDriverServer.exe

My GebConfig.groovy file where the drivers are instantiated:

```
ie {
    driver = {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities().internetExplorer().
        new RemoteWebDriver(new URI("http://<IP>:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities)
    }
}
```

My stack trace is as follows:

> geb.driver.DriverCreationException: failed to create driver from callback 'script13923985022291935133551$_run_closure2_closure5_closure9@557c6200'
>       at geb.driver.CallbackDriverFactory.getDriver(CallbackDriverFactory.groovy:35)
>       at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory.getDriver_closure3(CachingDriverFactory.groovy:80)
>       at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory.getDriver_closure3(CachingDriverFactory.groovy)
>       at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory$SimpleCache.get(CachingDriverFactory.groovy:30)
>       at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory.getDriver(CachingDriverFactory.groovy:79)
>       at geb.Configuration.createDriver(Configuration.groovy:354)
>       at geb.Configuration.getDriver(Configuration.groovy:343)
>       at geb.Browser.getDriver(Browser.groovy:105)
>       at geb.Browser.go(Browser.groovy:394)
>       at geb.Page.to(Page.groovy:184)
>       at geb.Browser.via(Browser.groovy:475)
>       at geb.Browser.to(Browser.groovy:434)
>       at geb.Browser.to(Browser.groovy:412)
>       at geb.spock.GebSpec.methodMissing(GebSpec.groovy:51)
>       at com.bloomhealthco.functional.LoginTestSpec.User is able to login as an administrator(LoginTestSpec.groovy:12)
>   Caused by: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver(java.net.URI, groovy.util.ConfigObject)
>       at script13923985022291935133551.run_closure2_closure5_closure9(script13923985022291935133551.groovy:44)
>       at script13923985022291935133551.run_closure2_closure5_closure9(script13923985022291935133551.groovy)
>       at geb.driver.CallbackDriverFactory.getDriver(CallbackDriverFactory.groovy:29)
>       ... 14 more
>
> geb.driver.DriverCreationException: failed to create driver from callback 'script13923985022291935133551$_run_closure2_closure5_closure9@557c6200'
>       at geb.driver.CallbackDriverFactory.getDriver(CallbackDriverFactory.groovy:35)
>       at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory.getDriver_closure3(CachingDriverFactory.groovy:80)
>       at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory.getDriver_closure3(CachingDriverFactory.groovy)
>       at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory$SimpleCache.get(CachingDriverFactory.groovy:30)
>       at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory.getDriver(CachingDriverFactory.groovy:79)
>       at geb.Configuration.createDriver(Configuration.groovy:354)
>       at geb.Configuration.getDriver(Configuration.groovy:343)
>       at geb.Browser.getDriver(Browser.groovy:105)
>       at geb.report.PageSourceReporter.getPageSource(PageSourceReporter.groovy:42)
>       at geb.report.PageSourceReporter.writePageSource(PageSourceReporter.groovy:38)
>       at geb.report.PageSourceReporter.writeReport(PageSourceReporter.groovy:29)
>       at geb.report.CompositeReporter.writeReport(CompositeReporter.groovy:31)
>       at geb.Browser.report(Browser.groovy:775)
>       at geb.spock.GebReportingSpec.report(GebReportingSpec.groovy:44)
>       at geb.spock.GebReportingSpec.cleanup(GebReportingSpec.groovy:39)
>   Caused by: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver(java.net.URI, groovy.util.ConfigObject)
>       at script13923985022291935133551.run_closure2_closure5_closure9(script13923985022291935133551.groovy:44)
>       at script13923985022291935133551.run_closure2_closure5_closure9(script13923985022291935133551.groovy)
>       at geb.driver.CallbackDriverFactory.getDriver(CallbackDriverFactory.groovy:29)
>       ... 14 more
>
> geb.driver.DriverCreationException: failed to create driver from callback 'script13923985022291935133551$_run_closure2_closure5_closure9@557c6200'
>       at geb.driver.CallbackDriverFactory.getDriver(CallbackDriverFactory.groovy:35)
>       at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory.getDriver_closure3(CachingDriverFactory.groovy:80)
>       at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory.getDriver_closure3(CachingDriverFactory.groovy)
>       at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory$SimpleCache.get(CachingDriverFactory.groovy:30)
>       at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory.getDriver(CachingDriverFactory.groovy:79)
>       at geb.Configuration.createDriver(Configuration.groovy:354)
>       at geb.Configuration.getDriver(Configuration.groovy:343)
>       at geb.Browser.getDriver(Browser.groovy:105)
>       at geb.Browser.clearCookies(Browser.groovy:483)
>       at geb.Browser.clearCookiesQuietly(Browser.groovy:491)
>       at geb.spock.GebSpec.resetBrowser(GebSpec.groovy:45)
>       at geb.spock.GebSpec.cleanup(GebSpec.groovy:67)
>   Caused by: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver(java.net.URI, groovy.util.ConfigObject)
>       at script13923985022291935133551.run_closure2_closure5_closure9(script13923985022291935133551.groovy:44)
>       at script13923985022291935133551.run_closure2_closure5_closure9(script13923985022291935133551.groovy)
>       at geb.driver.CallbackDriverFactory.getDriver(CallbackDriverFactory.groovy:29)
>       ... 11 more

Additionally the node can be registered with the hub:

[ip:4444/grid/console screenshot](http://s17.postimg.org/dqxevn1jz/Screen_Shot_2014_02_14_at_12_42_31_PM.png)

I've been searching all day and it seems this should work.  Does anyone have any suggestions or know what's wrong?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: can you telnet to the windows machine from the mac and vice versa?

Comment: I cannot telnet from Mac to Windows virtual machine, but I can from Windows to Mac.  I disabled the Windows firewall ending with the same results.

Comment: after disabling the firewall, could you telnet to the node port? If not, then the selenium grid will not be able to setup, the ports need to be listening

Comment: I change my networking (for now) to a bridged connection.  I am able now to telnet my windows vm.  However, I am still receiving the same error.

Comment: Additionally I have added firefox to the node and tried using grid to produce a test in firefox.  I run into the same error.  This means we can move past the location of IEServerDriver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your stacktrace I can see that the real reason for not being able to create the driver is:

```
 Could not find matching constructor for: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver(java.net.URI, groovy.util.ConfigObject)
```

Is the snipped of your GebConfig.groovy exactly the same as you have it in your file? I see that `capabilities` is defined as an instance of `DesiredCapabilities` in your snippet so I don't understand why would a config object be passed as the second parameter... I can't see it but maybe you have a typo somewhere? With Groovy config scripts you'll have issues if you mistype something as you will get a new empty `ConfigObject` instance instead of an error.

The second thing is that the first parameter should be an `URL` and not a `URI` if you're after using [this constructor](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.html#RemoteWebDriver%28java.net.URL,%20org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities%29).

Comment: Thank you, saw the error I had seen in the past and overlooked the stack trace.  It was  the URL vs URI parameter.  After that, problem solved.